# how to get/ view metadata from namenode in hadoop?

Tags: hdfs

In hadoop HDFS, how to get the metadata stored in namenode. Is it accessible or is hidden for security reasons. I tried getting the FSImage. But I could not view it.

Please explain.

Comment: Please provide us with a copy of the code you have tried and what the outcome was.

Comment: I did not try through code. I tried opening FSImage from file explorer in VMWare. It did not work. So I had asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

By using below command you can convert **namenode fsimage** into text and XML file

```
bash$ hdfs oiv -i path/to/fsimage/file -o destination/file
```

### Commands for XML and Text

```
bash$ hdfs oiv -i path/to/fsimage/file -o destination/file.xml -p XML
bash$ hdfs oiv -i path/to/fsimage/file -o destination/file.txt -p Indented
```

for more details please follow [this link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsImageViewer.html) you can understand clearly:-